# cann't push into the master branch on Git visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, gitlab

I have clone a gitlab project which I have developer permission on it. when I clone it , I can not push it back. it gives me this error message:

[image]

the repository is updated ( I pull first or even right away after clonning) then by making a very simple edit , commit it and I try to push it , but the above message appears, what should I do for that? where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons (more detail is required)
possible solutions(by given data in question)
1: sometimes developers do not have permission to push in master branch then you have to make a new branch using git checkout -b "Branch Name" then push it to repo
2: add ssh identity again using ssh-add then try

Comment: @@afzaalshoukat:  yes I have a branch of my own(name dev1branch), i can push on dev1branch. but not into master branch which I have developer permission on it

Comment: please add more (error) details then it could be authentication issue

Comment: the only error is on the post. it says "I can find more details on output windows" which is completely empty. how can I give you more error message?

Comment: I tried to push by command "git push origin master" and it said: 
"Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project."

Comment: @nnmmss: well, there you go: the problem is not your `git push`, it's that *you have no permissions here* (contrary to your original claim). Who owns the repository on GitLab? Why have they locked you out?